# Javascript: Sorting data and output

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem due to insufficient knowledge of Javascript. He uses plugins Maplace.js genenriruet list of objects in the `<div class="wrap_controls"></div>`.
The list looks like this:

```
    <ul class="ullist controls">
<li><a><span>A title 1</span></a></li>
<li><a><span>A title 5</span></a></li>
<li><a><span>A title 2</span></a></li>
<li><a><span>B title 3</span></a></li>
<li><a><span>B title 1</span></a></li>
<li><a><span>A title 6</span></a></li>
....
    </ul>
```

The list is created according to the order of entries in the database with the first record.
JS code that generates the list looks like this:

```
 getHtml: function () {

        var html = $("<ul class='ullist controls " + this.o.controls_cssclass + "'></ul>").css(this.o.controls_applycss ? {

            margin: 0,

            padding: 0,

            listStyleType: 'none'

        } : {}),

            title, a;



        if (this.ShowOnMenu(this.view_all_key)) {

            html.append($('<li></li>').append(html_ullist.html_a.call(this, false, this.view_all_key, this.o.view_all_text)));

        }



        for (a = 0; a < this.ln; a++) {

            if (this.ShowOnMenu(a)) {

                html.append($('<li></li>').append(html_ullist.html_a.call(this, a)));

            }

        }



        title = this.o.controls_title;

        if (this.o.controls_title) {

            title = $('<div class="controls_title"></div>').css(this.o.controls_applycss ? {

                fontWeight: 'bold',

                padding: '3px 10px 5px 0',

                fontSize: this.o.controls_on_map ? '12px' : 'inherit'

            } : {}).append(this.o.controls_title);

        }



        this.html_element = $('<div class="wrap_controls"></div>').append(title).append(html);



        return this.html_element;

    }
```

I want to sort the output and do so:

```
     <ul class="ullist controls">
<h2>A</h2>
<li><a><span>A title 1</span></a></li>
<li><a><span>A title 2</span></a></li>
<li><a><span>A title 5</span></a></li>
<li><a><span>A title 6</span></a></li>
<h2>B</h2>
<li><a><span>B title 1</span></a></li>
<li><a><span>B title 3</span></a></li>
....
    </ul>
```

I know how to do it correctly on PHP, but how to do it on Javascript, I do not know yet. I hope for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Possible approach(description inside the code):

```
jQuery(
  function($)
  {
    $('.ullist.controls').each(function(){
       var  //the current ul
            that    = $(this),
            //array with the li's
            items   = $.makeArray(that.find('li')),
            //used to store text of current heading
            heading = null;

       //native js-sorting based on the text
       items.sort(function(a,b){

         return (($(a).find('span').text()>$(b).find('span').text())
                  ? 1
                  :-1
                )
       });

       //iterate over sorted li's
       $.each(items,function(){
        //the first char in text
        var c=$(this).find('span').text().substr(0,1).toUpperCase();
        //when it's not equal to heading create a caption
        //note:use a styled li here because h2 is not a valid child for ul
        if(c!==heading){
          that.append($('<li/>').text(c).css({fontWeight:   'bold',
                                              listStyleType:'none',
                                              fontSize:     '1.2em'}));
          heading=c;
        }
        //append current li to the ul, this will sort the items in ul
        that.append(this);
       });
    });
  }
);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/LL748hvd/